# XCode 4.1 Documentation problem

Tags: xcode4, documentation

I've recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to OS X Lion and from XCode 3.2 to 4.1. But roughly said I'm unhappy with XCode. The reasons are many but the main one is I can't search the documentation installed. In 3.2 I used to be able to have incremental search-so as I typed class and other references where displayed and I could choose the one I needed. But in 4.1 most of the time I can't even type in the search area. It just freezes and won't let me type. Does anybody else have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite odd but after a while the problem with the documentation just disapperared. Now I can look up any API reference. But anyway i still find the old style Xcode and Documentation nicer and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 seems to require quite a bit more power to run smoothly. Since you're talking about something not specific to an individual project, I'm guessing it's performance in general.

For comparison: On a MacBook Air (not the latest but purchased earlier in 2011), it's "workable" but quite slow and seems to grow angry at the merest hint of the word "battery." It pauses frequently, doc searches are smooth if by "smooth" you mean "lined with brick walls." Conversely, on a (similarly next-to-latest) top of the line iMac with 16 GB RAM and a solid state drive, Xcode 4.1 has no apparent performance issues.

In other words, the new shiny might require a hardware upgrade to run smoothly.